# Trying to get Git LFS to Work on Comitted Files

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree, git-lfs

I am trying to get people to upload large files into git and am having problems where it asks for verification which is not working.  I'm trying to use LFS to make my files smaller in case the filesize is going above the limit set by git.

When I am trying to help people upload large files they get a warning message teeling them the file size is larger that 10MB when they click to stage the files.
We commit and then try to push which is when we see this error. 
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/708054618000588890/721937559550296074/unknown.png

"git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks push -v --tags --set-upstream origin MusicImplementation:MusicImplementation
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/Daniel-Nimitz/MetroidVania-Game-Jam/'
Pushing to https://github.com/Daniel-Nimitz/MetroidVania-Game-Jam />Completed with errors, see above."

Everyone on the team has Sourcetree installed and uses a Windows OS.

I have done the following to try to fix the issue:
I have had everyone download git LFS.
I then have them put this in their terminal: git lfs install
I have them change their .gitattribute file to this: https://gist.github.com/nemotoo/b8a1c3a0f1225bb9231979f389fd4f3f />To try to make .wav files smaller I tried to use this command: git lfs migrate import --include=".wav"
but when I did this then for some reason a bunch of the changes which were not staged went away leaving only one .wav file to upload when there had previously been many.  Not sure why this is, maybe something else went wrong.

Update:  I have found that this is most likely an issue having to do with git being unable to authenticate the users.  It may not have to do with file size.

Comment: Everyone on the team has Sourcetree installed and uses a Windows OS.


I have done the following to try to fix the issue:
I have had everyone download git LFS.
I then have them put this in their terminal: git lfs install
I have them change their .gitattribute file to this: https://gist.github.com/nemotoo/b8a1c3a0f1225bb9231979f389fd4f3f />To try to make .wav files smaller I tried to use this command: git lfs migrate import --include=".wav"